# iptables ip address block ignored?

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, iptables

Running `top` on our server gives us

> load average: 68.67, 63.48, 60.30

We suspect this is from too many httpd connections.

running:

```
netstat -tun 2>/dev/null | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
```

gives us (all IPs converted to private addresses):

```
418 
176 192.168.1.1
 41 192.168.1.2
  8 192.168.1.3
  5 192.168.1.4
  5 192.168.1.5
  4 192.168.1.6
  2 192.168.1.7
  2 192.168.1.8
  2 192.168.1.9
  2 127.0.0.1
  1 servers)
  1 Address
  1 192.168.1.10
  1 192.168.1.11
```

As you can see the `192.168.1.1` (converted from WAN address, just for here) it appears has 176 connections going to our server. A remote look up of this IP brings it back resolving to a DDOS service.

We've run

```
sudo iptables -I INPUT -m iprange --src-range 192.168.0.0-192.168.0.255 -j DROP
```

to try to drop all ranges associated with their full range but requests are still showing up when running the netstat command.

Is there something wrong with the IPtables command or netstat command?

We ran

```
 sudo service iptables save
 sudo service httpd restart
```

to store it and make it active and then

```
sudo iptables --list
```

to confirm it was added, which it was. Not sure if there's something we're missing. Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Running `iptables -L -nv` shows

```
pkts bytes target     prot opt in
30179 1793K DROP       all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           source IP range STARTRANGE-ENDRANGE
```

Does this mean `30179` requests were blocked?

Also our IPtables looks like this (STARTRANGE/ENDRANGE are actual quad octet addresses)...

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP)
target     prot opt source               destination         
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            source IP range STARTRANGE-ENDRANGE 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            source IP range STARTRANGE-ENDRANGE 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            source IP range STARTRANGE-ENDRANGE 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:http 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:https 
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
ACCEPT     icmp --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            state NEW tcp dpt:ssh 
ACCEPT     tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            tcp dpt:mysql 
DROP       all  --  anywhere             anywhere            source IP range STARTRANGE-ENDRANGE
```

Shortened Netstat output (command run: `netstat -n | grep '192.168'`):

```
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44531          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44675          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44600          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44587          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44641          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44578          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44626          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44604          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44541          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44678          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44625          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44661          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44543          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44602          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44644          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44580          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44688          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44683          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44588          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44556          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44681          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT    
tcp        0      1 OUR_SERVER_IP:44631          192.168.1.1:443          SYN_SENT
```

Comment: Yes, the packet count on that rule means that 30,179 packets matched it, and were dropped.

Comment: So does the `netstat` command just show incoming requests before it hits the IPtables?

Comment: No; generally, if `iptables` blocks something it shouldn't show up in `netstat`.  Exceptions include a connection that was valid before any `DROP` rule went in place, which will now have to age out *very slowly* (because you've blocked any RSTs from coming in).  But since you're not showing us any `netstat` output, and you're insisting on redacting the IP addresses in the `iptables` output, it's very hard to comment further.

Comment: Okay, thanks, updated with netstat output. The rules been in place for a little over an hour now so I'd think the connection would have died by now. Also  stopped the apache for 5 minutes.

Comment: Please, use the `-n` flag to `netstat`, too; the vagaries of your internal DNS aren't the interesting part of this question.

Comment: Okay, updated with `-n` flag.

Comment: Those look an awful lot like *outbound* connections to a remote HTTPS server (which of course can never be completed - because you're blocking the returning `SYN/ACK`, thus leaving the connection in `SYN_SENT` forever).  No?

Comment: Hmm I think we've past my networking knowledge. Were these pending requests that didn't complete when I put the DROP in place? Is there a way to flush these?

Comment: I doubt it.  Something on your server is trying to get to the HTTPS port on `192.168.1.1`, and the three-way handshake can't complete, because you're blocking it.  Find out what process wants to get to that HTTPS server, and apologise to the admin for breaking it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27066/discussion-between-user3783243-and-madhatter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now you've finally posted the `netstat` output in question (thank you for that), we can see that the connections it's picking up almost certainly aren't **from** the remote server, as you'd supposed.   Instead, your server is trying hard to initiate connections **to** that remote server on port 443 (HTTPS).  That's why they aren't being blocked by an `INPUT` chain rule; the first packet is *outbound* - only the response the remote server generates is blocked by the `INPUT` rule, leaving the connection in `SYN_SENT` until it times out.

Use of `netstat -apn` has shown that it's the HTTPD server on your system that's making these connections.  You don't know of any reasons why your server should be doing this, so you're going away to take a long hard look at its setup.

Comment: Maybe running an open proxy?

Comment: @AndréFernandes that's definitely a possibility.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `iptables -L -nv` to troubleshoot if the rules are matched. You will see in the first column `pkts` the number of packets that matched each rule.

If your rule is not matched, it could be that it was matched earlier by another firewall entry (rule).

Comment: Thanks, this shows additional information for me I'll update question with that information.

Comment: You're still editing in `iptables` output without `-nv`; please don't do that.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you run `iptables -I INPUT (...)` with the `rulenum` argument. You want to make sure this rule is inserted before any `-j ACCEPT` rule for the http port. The default for this argument is 1, so it should already be at the top.

`iptables -nvL --line-numbers` will print out your current iptables with the numbers for the rules.

```
$ iptables -nvL --line-numbers
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
num   pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

1      52  2640 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80
2       0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:443
3     415 42229 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
```

Running `iptables -I INPUT 2 <your-rule-here>` will add the rule before rule #2 in the output, pushing it down in the table.

You could replace your rule with `iptables -I INPUT -m iprange --src-range 192.168.0.0-192.168.0.255 -j LOG --log-prefix "BADGUYS"` instead of `-j DROP`. This will write log data to the syslog, where you can filter by the `BADGUYS` value given above. If this shows in the syslog then your filter is good and should drop the traffic.

You can keep both a `LOG`and a `DROP` line in the iptables rules (in that order).

Comment: Where does `LOG --log-prefix` log to? I tried googling but the `--log-prefix` is breaking my results, all I get is things on `logs`..

Comment: In redhat it logs to /var/log/messages